# Time calculation between openGL update calls

Tags: xna, opengl, timer

In XNA, the system calls update and draw function with the time information. This contains information such as how much time has passed since last update was called. This makes easy to integrate time and do animation calculation accordingly. But I dont see any such mechanism in openGL. I see openGL requires programmers to have their own implementation which could be buggy or inefficient. Is there any standard (and efficient) code that demonstrate this practice in openGL?

Comment: http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XNA can do this because it knows it's sitting on top of a Windows-like platform, and therefore has Windows-compatible timer functions. OpenGL can sit on top of any OS, and therefore it can't provide any such thing itself.

[GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) provides a lightweight cross-platform wrapper around OpenGL, including high-precision timing routines.

This is also something that is fairly straightforward to implement yourself, using `QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows, `mach_absolute_time` on OS X, and `clock_gettime` on POSIX (e.g. Linux).

Comment: There is no timer in OpenGL but it is strange. Running on multiple OSes isn't a reason. OpenGL is a framework for abstracting away from needing to know the OS and GPU. For example the XNA Framework works on WP7, Windows and the Xbox 360, 3 completely different machines (little endian, big endian, arm, x86) however since the XNA framework was written for all these systems, all these systems have the same time interface. (This could be easily added to OpenGL). However XNA is a game making framework (which always needs timing), while OpenGL is a graphics framework, so maybe that's the reason?

Comment: OpenGL has never been a framework for abstracting away from the OS.  OpenGL ES contains the first tiny steps towards such a thing with EGL. It exists to abstract away graphics card hardware. (Also, all three devices you name contain a Windows-based kernel, DirectX, and a CLR implementation. XNA depends on at least the latter two and probably in its primary incarnation a bit of the former as well.)

Comment: @Roy T. Yes, OpenGL is "Open Graphics Library", timing your game is logic and hence is not in the lib. This is also why OpenAL is a serperate library. XNA provides a framework for game development and hence tries to encompass everything needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think POSIX is a better option. Its also supported on mobile platforms like iPhone, Android etc.

Comment: You will need all three of those, assuming you want to port.